# Simple Date Parsing

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I've been struggling a strange question.

I'm trying to parse a date format looks like this

"Thu, 18 Aug 2016 16:25:25 GMT"

to only Month and date like this

"08/18"

well I use two `SimpleDateFormat`, to parse and format the input and output

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
```

however, everything seems to be correct when using genymotion emulator

but when it comes to the real phone, say sony Xperia Care

the following questions kept on comming

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 10 Aug 2016 15:40:57 GMT" (at offset 0)

so whats the reason that this happens?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your String-DAte has information that is related to an specific language, therefor you need to prepare the SimpleDAteFormat for such an information.
ERGO: you need to give a **Locale**

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
String dateStr = "Thu, 18 Aug 2016 16:25:25 GMT";
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = null;
d = inputFormat.parse(dateStr);
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
System.out.println("After format: " + outputFormat.format(d));
}
```